# response with appropriate mime type requested with accept

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, view, routes, laravel-5.1

Say I have a route:

```
Route::get('list',...);
```

If I call that route with `Accept: text/html` it should return a view with all the blade hoopla.
If I call that route with `Accept: application/json` it should return json, `Accept: application/xml` it will return xml.
And so on...

How do I realise that with Laravel 5.1?

Comment: quite unclear problem, can you elaborate it in detail please ?

Comment: Sorry what part is unclear?

Comment: I mean you will sent mime type and based on mime type you want to return that type of data data or file ?

Comment: Exactly. With my current level of knowledge (very basic) I would make routes for each or make a route with a parameter to send. But we have Accept so why not use that.

Comment: One way is making different routes for each mime type and pass to different function and return respective data or file, another way is to send  data to single function and then switch the return case based on mime type. Hope you understand :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle `Accept` header using these methods of the Request class:

> bool accepts(string|array $contentTypes)

If you just care about Json and HTML there is

> bool acceptsJson() / bool wantsJson()
>
> bool acceptsHtml()